# Button in fragment not doing anything onClick

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I know this question has been asked several times but I could not find the answer for my specific situation.

So i have this fragment `BottomSheetFrag.java` that is inflated when a button in `DialogsActivity.jaja` is clicked, and in this fragment there is a button with the id of `ride` where when clicked i want to start another activity called MainRideActivity.class.

Here in `DialogsActivity.jaja` is when the fragment is inflated:

```
floatingButtonContainer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
           // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet,null);
            BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getParentActivity());
            dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.show();       
        });
```

And this is the BottomSheetFrag.java

```
public class BottomSheetFrag  extends BottomSheetDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    public BottomSheetFrag(){

    }
    private Button mRideButton;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false);

        mRideButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ride);
        mRideButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View rootView) {
        switch (rootView.getId()) {
            case R.id.ride:
                Log.d("jojojo", "**************** The button has been clicked *****************");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainRideActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that whenever I click the button in the fragment nothing happens.

Comment: what about the Log ? Do you read ******** The button has been clicked ***** ?

Comment: @Francesco D'Onorio De Meo
No not even the long is appearing, i even searched fo the log with its tag but nothing.